# Using jq to extract values and format in CSV

Tags: json, csv, format, extract, jq

I have the below json file:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "displayName": "First Name",
        "rank": 1,
        "value": "VALUE"
    },
    {
        "displayName": "Last Name",
        "rank": 2,
        "value": "VALUE"
    },
    {
        "displayName": "Position",
        "rank": 3,
        "value": "VALUE"
    },
    {
        "displayName": "Company Name",
        "rank": 4,
        "value": "VALUE"
    },
    {
        "displayName": "Country",
        "rank": 5,
        "value": "VALUE"
    },
]
}
```

I would like to have a CSV file in this format:

`First Name, Last Name, Position, Company Name, Country`

`VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE`

Is this possible by using only jq? I don't have any programming and/or great command-line skills.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is:

```
.data | sort_by(.rank) | map(.displayName), map(.value) | @csv
```

Comment: I down voted this before I understood the question. It is locked now, but I will upvote when that lock is removed.